# Convertir registros de una tabla a objeto en una misma query

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo una clase en mi solución así:

```
public class EmailMasivo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

Y en la base de datos, hay una tabla Email, que ademas de esos dos atributos tiene varios mas. Para tomar como ejemplo supongamos que la tabla EmailDB tiene ademas de Id y Mail, **borrado y fechaCreacion**.

Yo lo que quiero saber es como puedo transformar varios EmailDB a Email en una query. Les explico, tengo esta query:

```
var listaEmails = await db.EMail.Where(x => listaEnNEmail.Contains(x.Id) && !x.Borrado).ToListAsync();
```

Quisiera que listaEmails sea una lista de Email, no de EmailDB. Trate haciendo algo por el estilo:

```
var listaEmails = await db.EMail.Where(x => listaEnNEmail.Contains(x.Id) && !x.Borrado)
                                    .Select(new List<EmailMasivo>() { /*aca las propiedades */ }).ToListAsync();
```

Pero no funciona, alguna sugerencia?
Gracias.

Comment: Cuando dice que la solucion que propone "no funciona" se refiere a que le da un error? O que no tiene el comportamiento que usted espera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que falta corregir la parte del `.Select()` , donde no deberías buscar instanciar una `List<EmailMasivo>`, ya que la ejecución del método será por cada uno de los ítems encontrados en el `.Where()`. Entonces, en el `.Select()` debes indicar qué hacer con cada ítems considerado, y no pretender allí ya generar la lista. Luego, al final de la ejecución el método, te devolverá una instancia de `IEnumerable<T>`, donde `T` es el tipo genérico logrado. Una vez que tiene ese objeto, lo puedes convertir a una `List<T>` o `ListAsync<T>` o lo que te convenga más.

```
var listaEmails = await db.EMail.Where(x => listaEnNEmail.Contains(x.Id) && !x.Borrado)
.Select(x => new EmailMasivo() { Id = x.Id, Mail = x.Mail }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: No es bien visto solicitar que el OP te marque el aporte como aceptado (*al menos no dentro del cuerpo de la respuesta*), eso lo decidirá si le funciona o no, por otro lado en la zona de comentarios si el te indica que le ha funcionado le puedes pedir lea esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers